# Getting error when publising variants

Tags: magnolia

I am getting the following error while publishing Variants in Pages. But I am able to Publish all the Pages except Variants.
[image]

Could you please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

-Vijay Kodali.

Comment: You need to provide more information. At the very least, snippet containing error that appeared in the log. Exact version of Magnolia and app server you are running it on. It would also help to know whether or not you have customised workflow (Seems like you did because of the untranslated workflow message in the screenshot) and if you did then what exactly did you do. What else ... workflow is part of enterprise edition, so assuming you have enterprise, you might want to open support request with Magnolia to help you.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace http://pastebin.com/0w3W5Ju6    We are using Magnolia version 5.3.9. using derby store.

Answer (score 0):

It is Working fine for me now, after purging the version of previously deleted content.

i.e. Tools->Repository Tools>>>> Click on PURGE VERSIONS

Thanks,
Vijay Kodali.